# Can I reuse a CAAnimationGroup by returning it from a layer's animationForKey:?

Tags: ios, core-animation

I'm trying to do something like:

```
<Create a CAAnimationGroup aGroup with removedOnCompletion = NO ...>
[aLayer addAnimation:aGroup forKey:@"someKey"];
```

So the animation group plays...

And then I'd want to retrieve the same animation group without recreating it and re-add it to the layer so that it replays. Something like:

```
CAAnimationGroup* theOldGroup = (CAAnimationGroup*)[aLayer animationForKey:@"someKey"];
[aLayer addAnimation:theOldGroup forKey:@"someKey"];
```

However, the address of aGroup is different than the one I get back from animationForKey. And trying to set its speed to 1 or doing anything with it crashes the app (aka BAD_ACCESS)

What am I missing?

Comment: If you want to reuse the animation, why don't you store it in a variable/property? If you want to make it run again, why don't you set the repeatCount of the animation group?

Comment: because I think it can be done this way. Sure, I could store it in a variable or even not use a group and create the sequence in a block which I'd re-dispatch. But I'm trying to figure out if it is doable this way too.

Comment: Read the docs again, it can't be done this way. (see my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't reuse them the way you are describing in your question.

---

The [documentation for `animationForKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) says you can't do it this way (in the **discussion**):

> ### animationForKey:
>
> Returns the animation added to the receiver with the specified identifier.
>
> `- (CAAnimation *)animationForKey:(NSString *)key`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *key*
> A string that specifies the identifier of the animation.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> The animation object matching the identifier, or `nil` if no such animation exists.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Attempting to modify any properties of the returned object will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok I guess I can't. Though the reason why I thought maybe it was possible was cause I had read the documentation (including your quotation) but Xcode wasn't bitching about me trying to modify a read-only object. But then again, that would only be the case had I tried accessing an object as a property through an accessor.